# How to skip parentheses on Netbeans with enter?

Tags: eclipse, ide, netbeans

So I have been programming in C++ with Eclipse and have the habit of hitting enter to skip parentheses (anyone who has ever used eclipse probably knows what I am talking about).

I have recently started learning Java and decided to use NetBeans, mostly due to the much more simple interface.

However, I would like to know if there a way to skip the (), [], <> and "" on enter just like what happens in Eclipse in NetBeans.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This should be this option:

[image]

From the [general Editor features](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html):

> By default, the IDE automatically inserts matching pairs of braces, brackets, and quotes.
>   **When you type an opening curly brace and then press Enter, the closing brace is added automatically**.
>   For (, [, ", and ', the editor inserts a matching pair right away.
>   If, for some reason, this feature is disabled, enable it as follows:
>   `Choose Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion`.
>   Select the `Insert Closing Brackets Automatically` checkbox.
>
> The editor also highlights matching pairs of braces, brackets and quotes.
>   For example, place the cursor before any brace or bracket and, if it has a matching pair, both will be highlighted in yellow.
>   Single brackets of any type are highlighted in red and the error mark is displayed in the lefthand margin.
>   To customize the highlight colors, choose `Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Highlighting`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was useful, however, that wasn't what I was looking for.